# Redirect link in SMS messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, content-builder, sms

Is it possible to add the URL link to a specific word in an SMS? For example:

> Please visit our **[website](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)** for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SMS does not support html tags. Consider using a link shortener like bit.ly